# Ruby Euler project Non-abundant sums 23 Code

Tags: ruby

An [*abundant number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is greater than the number itself. A [Project Euler question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23) says: "Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers." I should get:

```
12, 18, 20, 24, etc.
```

The code is:

```
def check_abundant(x)
  total(x) > x
end

def total (x)
  sum = 1
  (2..Math.sqrt(x)).each do |i|
    sum = sum + x + x/i if x%i == 0 && i != Math.sqrt(x)
  end
  sum
end

def non_abundant_sums
  abundant_arr = []
  s = 0
  (12..28123).each do |x|
    if check_abundant(x)
      abundant_arr << x
    end
    (1..28123).each do |x|
      s = s + x unless abundant_arr.include? (total(x) - x)
    end
    s
  end
  puts non_abundant_sums
```

When I print `abundant_arr`, I get

```
12, 14, 15
```

Comment: You're going to have to do more than throw a bunch of code up and say what answer you get. What is the **problem**?

Comment: I suggest you edit to move your penultimate paragraph to the very top. Also, please define "abundant number".

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's part of it. The other part is explaining in more specific terms what this is supposed to achieve. What is "abundant?"

Comment: @CarySwoveland My move is get the abundant number arr and check the integers before 28213 to see if there is number included in abundant number array.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the definition of an abundant number.  With that, the question is probably clear enough.  However, I would recommend that the indentation of the Ruby code be fixed. @Haohsuanwang, could you please edit the question to fix the indentation of the Ruby code?

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, I have edited the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started. It will take a while to finish.

```
def proper_divisors(num)
  (1...num).select { |n| num % n == 0 }
end

def abundant?(n)   
  proper_divisors(n).reduce(:+) > n
end 

arr = (12..28123).map { |n| print "." if n % 100 == 0; n if abundant?(n) }.compact
 => [12, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40...]
```

Comment: really appreciated!!